# identify scope oauth2 discord.py

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get user informations with the identify scope. This is the code I tried and which is not working.

```
def identify(access_token):
    url="https://discordapp.com/api/v8/users/@me"

    headers = {
        "Authorization" : f"Bot {access_token}"
    }

    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Error:

```
{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}
```

I get the error with  `"Authorization" : f"Bot {access_token}"` but I tried using the discord application token, instead of the access token, and I successfully got the bot informations without any error. The access token I am using is not expired.

Answer (score 0):

In headers

```py
headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
    }
```

change the *Bot* to **Bearer** and it should work just fine